# How to keep question marks for input field values in GET forms?

Tags: html

I have an HTML form like the following:

```html
<form method="GET" name="search" action="/api">
Name: <input type="url" name="url" />
<input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

If I input some value in the URL field like `www.google.com?teste=a`, I receive on my server-side the following value from the parameter `www.google.com teste=a` (notice the question mark disappeared).

Is it possible to fix this without using JavaScript to receive the question mark on the server-side?

Comment: Are you URL encoding your data?

Comment: No, it's not encoding

Comment: Do you have to use `GET` for the form method? Using GET will generate a proper querystring with the `?` and you cannot have multiple `?`

Comment: I need it because there are dependencies on the URL parameters when the page refreshes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing the form method to `POST` you could possibly use Javascript to modify the value of the URL field just prior to submitting the form itself.

```js
document.forms.search.bttn.addEventListener('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  this.previousElementSibling.value=encodeURIComponent(this.previousElementSibling.value);
  this.parentNode.submit()
});
```

```html
<form method="GET" name="search" action="/api">
  Name: <input type="url" name="url" />
  <input type="submit" name='bttn' value="Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: Is it possible to encode for a different format? 
Let's say the meta defines the charset as UTF-8 but I want to encode to ISO-8859-1